# Javascript object method is not a function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have been searching here and haven't found something that quite matches, of course correct me if I'm wrong. This seems simple but I cannot see the reason.

```
    function Dice() {
    if (!(this instanceof Dice)) {
        return new Dice();
    };
    this.sides = 6
};

Dice.prototype.setUpDieForHTML = function(roll) {

    const die = [
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-one.svg',
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-two.svg',
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-three.svg',
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-four.svg',
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-five.svg',
        'C:\\projects\\apoc\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-six.svg'
    ];
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    const dice = $('.dice');

    img.classList.add('dice-size');
    img.setAttribute('src', die[roll]);
    dice.append(img);
}

Dice.prototype.dieRoll = function() {
    let result = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    switch (result) {
        case 1:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
        case 2:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
        case 3:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
        case 4:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
        case 5:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
        default:
            this.setUpDieForHTML(result);
            break
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Dice
};
```

When I instantiate the object and call dieRoll() I get setUpDieForHTML is not a function. I have moved the code around, changed to a class, run directly in Node REPL it seems to recognize the functions. Also in the dev tools of chrome the instance object has the functions until called.

index.js

```
'use strict'
const die = require('./js/gamePieces/dice')
const newDie = new die.Dice()

$(() => {

    debugger
    $('.die-start-icon').on('click', newDie.dieRoll)
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Fallout Meeples</title>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Do not add `link` tags-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Do not add `script` tags-->
    <script src="public/vendor.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    <script src="public/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main id="apoc" class="game-area">
        <section class="player-start-area border yellow">
            <h2>Player One</h2>
            <section id="playerOne-dice">
                <div class="dice">
                    <img class="die-start-icon dice-size" src="./assets/img/perspective-dice-six-faces-random.svg">
                    <!--C:\\projects\\apoc\\assets\\img\\perspective-dice-six-faces-random.svg-->
                </div>
            </section>

        </section>
        <section class="player-start-area border blue">
            <h2>Player Two</h2>
            <section id="playerTwo-dice">
                <div class="dice"></div>
            </section>

        </section>
        <div class="dice"></div>


    </main>

    <!-- <script src="./assets/scripts/js/gamePieces/dice.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

I know there are some other issues in my code but this one thing I couldn't figure out.

Comment: When I paste your code into an editor, there are a bunch of invisible characters between each function, and they'll cause syntax errors that prevent the functions from being defined.

Comment: While semi-colons are not strictly necessary between lines, sometimes not having them can cause wierd parsing issues.  Probably better to include them

Comment: @Barmar I ran dos2Unix on the files to remove those characters, which editor did you see them in? I am using WSL and VS Code for my dev stuff right now. This did not resolve my issue, sadly.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I went and added in semicolons where appropriate and this also did not resolve my issue, thank you for the idea though.

Comment: All of your switch cases do exactly the same thing... Please include the HTML and where you instantiate the object and call dieRoll.

Comment: They looked like bullets when I pasted the code into the SO snippet editor. When I copied it into Emacs, it saysthe hex code is `5396b`

Comment: This character is alone on the lines before `img.classList.add('dice-size')`, `Dice.prototype.dieRoll = function`, and before the `}` that ends that function.

Comment: yes in jsfiddle i do see those bullet chars. even after cleaning it up with d0s2Linux. hmm

Comment: If the problem is that there are some wierd characters in the file, then why not create a new file and manually copy the contents?

Comment: This is the character you've got, by the way: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: Thanks all I have tried all of your suggestions. I think I need to retype it in vim and see what happens.